# Allowing a web user to make a color selection off a color wheel

Tags: javascript, html

The client wants to be able to designate a color for a data item, lets say cities, which will show the city name  and the selected color

For example: [image]

The color is storied in the database with the city information.

Does anyone know is there a web color wheel i can display on my page that will allow the user to select a color?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `<input>` element with its `type` attribute set to `"color"`:

```html
<input id="demo" type="color" />
```

This isn't guaranteed to be a colour *wheel*, as such, but it will serve in compliant browsers<sup>[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color)</sup> as a colour-picker.

References:

- [`<input type="color" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color).